# Assembly Language Operand Specifiers

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-registers, att

I am new to learning assembly language and came across the following expressions:

- `9(%rax, %rdx)`
- `0xFC(,%rcx,4)`
- `(%rax, %rdx, 4)`

I would be really grateful if someone could point me to a resource where I can understand these commands or explain them to me.

Thank you.

Comment: Consider reading a tutorial on AT&T assembly syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This apparently refers to arithmetic addressing in x86 AT&T assembly.

The syntax is rather simple:

```
N(%reg1, %reg2, F)
```

This results in `address = N + %reg1 + %reg2 * F`. This can be used in multiple instructions for purposes like accessing data inside a struct (C compilers), etc.

For full reference, check [this guide](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse374/16wi/lectures/20-x86_addressing_arithmetic.html).

Comment: Thank you so much. The link is really helpful.

Comment: That reference leaves out RIP-relative addressing modes, but otherwise looks good.  See also [all the available x86 addressing modes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34058400/224132).